# Parse XML to JSON Elixir

Tags: json, xml, elixir, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

anyone knows How to convert xml into json. I tried Sweetyxml but its not converting xml into json.

Using this gist
https://gist.github.com/spint/40717d4e6912d8cea929
Reading json

```
{:ok, xmldoc} = File.read(Path.expand("/Users/sohaibanwar/Desktop/unconfirmed_order.xml"))
```

```
{doc, []} = xmldoc |> to_charlist() |> :xmerl_scan.string() 
After parsing (in screenshot), but not getting right answer
```

*YML FILE I am using*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<order>
    <orderId>35267684</orderId>
    <orderToken>fa74171d-f54a-4e76-bcf2-2dd284ac6450</orderToken>
    <brokerTicketId>169855177</brokerTicketId>
    <section>SEC1</section>
    <row>N</row>
    <seats/>
    <notes>Limited view. Please note that you will need to use an iOS or Android mobile device to gain entry to your event.</notes>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <cost>324.00</cost>
    <event>Dave Matthews Band (Rescheduled from 7/17/2020, 7/16/2021)</event>
    <eventDate>2021-08-20 19:30:00</eventDate>
    <orderDate>2021-06-18 05:43:13</orderDate>
    <expectedShipDate>2021-06-18 00:00:00</expectedShipDate>
    <venue>Xfinity Center - MA - Mansfield, MA</venue>
    <status>UNCONFIRMED</status>
    <purchaseOrderId>35088971</purchaseOrderId>
    <electronicDelivery>false</electronicDelivery>
    <passThrough></passThrough>
    <listingId>3359267717</listingId>
    <productionId>3412459</productionId>
    <eventId>218</eventId>
    <zone>false</zone>
    <barCodesRequired>false</barCodesRequired>
    <transferViaURL>true</transferViaURL>
    <instantTransfer>false</instantTransfer>
    <instantFlashSeats>false</instantFlashSeats>
</order>
```

*Required Results*
You can paster the XML here to get the required answer

```
{
  "order": {
    "orderId": 35267684,
    "orderToken": "fa74171d-f54a-4e76-bcf2-2dd284ac6450",
    "brokerTicketId": 169855177,
    "section": "SEC1",
    "row": "N",
    "seats": "",
    "notes": "Limited view. Please note that you will need to use an iOS or Android mobile device to gain entry to your event.",
    "quantity": 2,
    "cost": 324,
    "event": "Dave Matthews Band (Rescheduled from 7/17/2020, 7/16/2021)",
    "eventDate": "2021-08-20 19:30:00",
    "orderDate": "2021-06-18 05:43:13",
    "expectedShipDate": "2021-06-18 00:00:00",
    "venue": "Xfinity Center - MA - Mansfield, MA",
    "status": "UNCONFIRMED",
    "purchaseOrderId": 35088971,
    "electronicDelivery": false,
    "passThrough": "",
    "listingId": 3359267717,
    "productionId": 3412459,
    "eventId": 218,
    "zone": false,
    "barCodesRequired": false,
    "transferViaURL": true,
    "instantTransfer": false,
    "instantFlashSeats": false
  }
}
```

Comment: It’s absolutely unclear what are you trying to achieve. Please come up with the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry @AlekseiMatiushkin I made it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your question is `How to convert xml to json in Elixir` the answer is fairly simple: use https://github.com/homanchou/elixir-xml-to-map and JSON encoder of your choice:

```
def xml2json(path) do
  File.read!(path)
  |> XmlToMap.naive_map()
  |> Jason.encode!()
end
```

The problem with this answer is that XML is not isomorphic to map (you have both tags and attributes in XML and you don't in map or JSON), so the better way will be to use `SweetXML` (or `:xmerl`) and do xmap with a proper match like here (code is from SweetXML examples - https://github.com/kbrw/sweet_xml#examples):

```
result = doc |> xmap(
  matchups: [
    ~x"//matchups/matchup"l,
    name: ~x"./name/text()",
    winner: [
      ~x".//team/id[.=ancestor::matchup/@winner-id]/..",
      name: ~x"./name/text()"
    ]
  ],
  last_matchup: [
    ~x"//matchups/matchup[last()]",
    name: ~x"./name/text()",
    winner: [
      ~x".//team/id[.=ancestor::matchup/@winner-id]/..",
      name: ~x"./name/text()"
    ]
  ]
)
assert result == %{
  matchups: [
    %{name: 'Match One', winner: %{name: 'Team One'}},
    %{name: 'Match Two', winner: %{name: 'Team Two'}},
    %{name: 'Match Three', winner: %{name: 'Team One'}}
  ],
  last_matchup: %{name: 'Match Three', winner: %{name: 'Team One'}}
}
```

Another option is to use https://github.com/willemdj/erlsom and do manual travers over tuple tree it emits from the `simple_form` call. Note you will have to handle XMLNS and attr/value problem anyways.